# How can I access a txt file in a jar with FileInputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream

I am aware of the `getResourceAsStream()` method but there is an issue with the parser that reads the file, the whole structure was implemented to expect a `FileInputStream()` and the `getResourceAsStream()` returns an input stream which cannot be casted. Is there any easy "fix" for this situation?

Comment: This would be why it's a good idea to code to the interface and not the implementation.

Comment: You shouldn't cast input streams to their implementations. Their are thought for implementing pipe&filters. It is, one (file)inputsrteam reads from a file, another decompress (GZipI.S.), another breaks lines (bufferedI.S.), another... and so on. So if your program expects a stream of bytes expect an inputstream (any I.S.) and then provide some of its implementations. If you want to transform the stream concatenate one with another: new GZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(path)) by example.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A resource contained within a JAR file is not itself a file, and cannot be read using a `FileInputStream`. If you have code that absolutely requires a `FileInputStream`, then you'll need to extract the data using `getResourceAsStream()`, copy it into a temporary file, then pass a `FileInputStream` for that temporary file to your code.

Of course, in future, never write code to expect concrete implementations of things like `InputStream`, you'll always regret it.

Answer (score 5):

I recently encountered the same issue. A third-party library we use reads from FileInputStream but the resources can be anywhere, in a JAR or remote. We used to write to temporary files but that has too much overhead.

A better solution is write a FileInputStream which wraps InputStream. Here is the class we use,

```
public class VirtualFileInputStream extends FileInputStream {

    private InputStream stream;

    public VirtualFileInputStream(InputStream stream) {
        super(FileDescriptor.in); // This will never be used
        this.stream = stream;
    }




    public int available() throws IOException {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unimplemented method called");
    }


    public void close() throws IOException {
        stream.close();
    }


    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return stream.equals(obj);
    }


    public FileChannel getChannel() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unimplemented method called");
    }


    public int hashCode() {
        return stream.hashCode();
    }


    public void mark(int readlimit) {
        stream.mark(readlimit);
    }


    public boolean markSupported() {
        return stream.markSupported();
    }


    public int read() throws IOException {
        return stream.read();
    }


    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        return stream.read(b, off, len);
    }


    public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        return stream.read(b);
    }


    public void reset() throws IOException {
        stream.reset();
    }


    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        return stream.skip(n);
    }


    public String toString() {
        return stream.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 but I'd call it FakeFileInputStream to underline the need of faking things :) and encourage to not using the concrete FileInputStream implementation.

Answer (score 0):

don't believe your parse only works on FileInputStream but not InputStream

if that is the real case, and you must use that parser

2 options

1. use adapter pattern to create a CustomFileInputStream and overwrite the respective methods, more of redirect the getResourceAsStream data to the CustomFileInputStream
2. save ur getResourceAsStream into a temp file, and parse the temp file, then delete the file when done